# Pop last array element with aggregation pipeline in Mongo DB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have this code to remove array element and unset array field if it is empty after operation:

```
db.collection.update(
  { "array": 1 },
  [{
    $set: {
      array: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$array",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", 1] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      array: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$array", []] },
          "$$REMOVE",
          "$array"
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

Is it possible to pop last array element and unset array field if it is empty after operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$slice` operator to remove the last element from the last position,

- `$size` to get total elements in `array`
- `$subtract` to minus 1 from the above total elements
- `$slice` to slice total elements from top to above return number

```
db.collection.update(
  { "array": { $ne: [] } },
  [{
    $set: {
      array: {
        $slice: [
          "$array",
          { $subtract: [{ $size: "$array" }, 1] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      array: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$array", []] }, "$$REMOVE", "$array"]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fLqbvyMqp3O)